# Why longtext field always empty in doctrine?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have LONGTEXT column in mysql DB.
In my entity class i have

```
 **
 * @ORM\Column(name="tmpl_content", type="text",  nullable=false)
 * @Assert\NotNull()
 */
protected $tmpl_content
```

CRUD operations are autogenerated.
Saving enitity is fine - i can save text and see it in phpmyadmin.
But when entity is loaded like that(autogenerated code)

```
$entity = $em->getRepository('AcmeMailmanagerBundle:Templates')->find($id);
```

My LONGTEXT column is always empty.
I tried to change LONGTEXT into VARCHAR and annotation to string- all worked fine, so something wrong with text datamapping.

Any ideas how fix it?

Comment: How did you try to access to $tmpl_content ? Did you only attempt a var_dump() or did you try with the getter (getTmplContent() i guess...) ?

Comment: Both. var_dump($entity), or entity.tmpcontent in twig temlate, or $entity->getTmplContent() - all of this methods return empty fied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its a problem with doctrine and the mysqli driver, i changed the driver from

```
database_driver: mysqli
```

to

```
database_driver: pdo_mysql
```

and its working... i will investigate furter and submit a bug report